# stdlib module is not detected

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have a module which reportedly required `puppetlabs-stdlib`.

```
[vagrant@learn puppet]$ sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list --tree --modulepath=/vagrant/puppet -v
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-stdlib':
  'elk' (v0.1.0) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (>= 1.0.0)
/vagrant/puppet
└─┬ elk (v0.1.0)
  └── UNMET DEPENDENCY puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 1.0.0)
```

I installed the module as follows:

```
[vagrant@learn puppet]$ sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib
Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppet.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v6.1.0)
```

However, the missing dependency is not resolved still. How can I make Puppet see the lib that I installed?

Comment: It looks like you installed stdlib into a different environment, and probably an entirely different Puppet installation than the one containing elk.  It's hard to be confident, however, because you haven't presented any of the actual commands you're running or any of the other details necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have updated the post. I don't think the environments are different. Please let me know why you think so.

Comment: I think the environments are different because elk is shown installed in `/vagrant/puppet` whereas stdlib is shown installed in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules`.  The latter is (by default) in the modulepath for the "production" environment, and it oughtn't to be in that for any other environment.  It is also the default destination for `puppet module install`.  It remains unclear which environment or even which Puppet installation has `/vagrant/puppet` in its modulepath.  Also, the whole unmet dependency thing is a good sign.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `/vagrant/puppet` is not a puppet installation. it is rather the name of the dir where puppet module source code, i.e. `elk` module is present. There are no two installations of Puppet.

Comment: There do not need to be multiple installations of Puppet for there to be multiple environments.  However, upon closer examination of the actual command issued, a simpler explanation becomes apparent.  I will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

> ```
> sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list --tree --modulepath=/vagrant/puppet -v
> ```

Reports that the `elk` module's dependency on `puppetlabs-stdlib` is unmet, whereas you show that module to be installed in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules`.  These facts are consistent.

The `--modulepath` argument to `puppet module list` does not do what you seem to expect.  This might be more clear if you took into account [Puppet's definition of the term](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.10/dirs_modulepath.html):

> The master service and the puppet apply command load most of their
>   content from modules found in one or more directories. The list of
>   directories where Puppet looks for modules is called the *modulepath*.
>   The modulepath is set by the current node's environment.
>
> The modulepath is an ordered list of directories, with earlier
>   directories having priority over later ones. Use the system path
>   separator character to separate the directories in the modulepath
>   list. On *nix systems, use a colon (:); on Windows use a semi-colon
>   (;).

The `--modulepath` option to your `puppet module list` command expresses a complete modulepath, and accordingly, in your command it tells Puppet to consider only modules in `/vagrant/puppet`.  With respect to that modulepath, the stdlib dependency is indeed unmet.

This alternative should show the dependency satisfied:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list --tree \
  --modulepath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/vagrant/puppet -v
```

What significance either result has at Puppet runtime depends on the modulepath Puppet is using for catalog building.  If you leave off the `--modulepath` option altogether then you will get results relevant to Puppet's current configuration and default environment, which might or might not be more relevant to your actual usage scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the same modulepath.

In the first instance, you are listing modules from `/vagrant/puppet` as per your --modulepath statement.

When you install, you did not specify a modulepath, so as per std out of the install:
`Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules`

So you have to either point the stdlib install to the same path: `puppet module --modulepath=/vagrant/puppet install puppetlabs-stdlib`, or update the modulepath of the client to run off the default, `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules`